# There is no activate when I am trying to run my virtual env

Tags: virtualenv, virtual-environment

1) I installed virtualenv using pip.
2) I ran the command `virtualenv venv`
3) Then I ran `source venv/bin/activate` but it says that there is no such file or directory.

When I `cd` into `venv/bin` I find 3 things - python, python 2.7, and python 3.5.  Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Just to check: what OS are you running this on?  (Windows virtualenv, at least the one in front of me, puts activate in the scripts directory but then again, it also puts python in there vs bin)  (Also, what other directories does venv have?)

Comment: I'm running it on mac osx.  Venv also has include and lib.  I feel like I downloaded too many versions of python now its screwing everything up.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not used to virtualenv dropping down both python 2.7 and 3.5 as the result of running the command once... can you run virtualenv new-venv-18-Jan (or some other name that you've absolutely never used before), and include all the output you get from running that command? (Assuming you still don't get activate in the new virtualenv)

Comment: Its says:
New python executable in...
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
Complete output from command...
ImportError: dlopen ... Symbol not found ... Expected in: flat namespace
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
Thats pretty much a summary of what it says

Comment: So you ran `sudo pip install virtualenv` on your system Python? You really aren't giving us much help here ...

Comment: For some weird reason the `activate` files were created without the execute file privileges (664 to be precise). Changing the permissions didn't help though.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil This is intentional. You shouldn't execute `activate`, but source it e.g. "source activate" or ". activate" (note space)

Answer (score 38):

i have had the same problem. and what i did is just run the command
`virtualenv env`
again. And then more files were generated under directory env/bin, including the activate file.  it's so weird.

Comment: This works. Slightly disconcerting that we don't know why. Not all the scripts were actually present in the bin directory.

Comment: You might have moved the env folder after creating it the first time.

Comment: The exact same thing occurred to me. Running `virtualenv venv` twice solved the problem. Never happened to me before.

Comment: I followed this advice and re-run the `virtualenv env` command. BUT interestingly my terminal prompted: 
**The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

   apt install python3.10-venv**

which didn't yell these initially. I installed the package and it works like a charm. hope this might help someone.

OS: ubuntu 22.04 
pyhton3: v3.10.4

Answer (score 11):

According to [Python doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/), the installation step is

```sh
$ python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv

$ python3 -m venv env
```

The last command gives a warning message,

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.
```

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

Now, `activate` is available.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the similar problem running `python3.7 -m venv venv`, you can change for your version of python that is installed in your enviroment.

Comment: Does anyone understand why the activate file disappeared?

Comment: Similar solution: `python -m venv .venv` works, `python3 -m venv .venv` does not include the activate.bat and other files. I did not have the time to tshoot, just adding confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

This is old but just wanted to add an answer that might be the case, though I can't be sure.

However this same thing happened to me when I accidentally ran `python -m venv venv` before installing `python-venv` (change according to your python version) in Ubuntu.  Most likely after I installed `python-venv` and ran it again it didn't overwrite the existing `venv` folder.  Had to remove manually and rerun command.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by naming it venv2 when I ran virtualenv.  I already had a virtual environment named venv for another project.  This allowed me to proceed.

Comment: It seems to have a problem with the name venv

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem when using the `--upgrade` option. Removed the option, and all ran as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen on rasbian when I hadn't installed `python3-pip` before creating the venv.

Answer (score 0):

I double it is caused by some networking issue, I run it twice to get 'activate' script installed. Maybe first it can't connect to some source so it just abort installation.