# Why is the `bin` directory named differently (`Scripts`) on Windows?

Tags: python, virtualenv, portability, virtual-environment

The [`venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (shipped with Python 3.3 or later), and [`virtualenv`](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), still widely in use, allow to install a project's dependencies not to the system-wide Python installation, but to a directory specific to that project.

One of the subdirectories of such a "virtual environment" contains a copy of the Python interpreter as well as "activate" and "deactivate" scripts - but this subdirectory is called `Scripts` on Windows, and `bin` on all other systems.

This is [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687841/there-is-no-activate-when-i-am-trying-to-run-my-virtual-env) [surprising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206990/virtualenv-env-not-creating-bin-directory-in-windows-7/13206997). **Why did they special-case Windows?**

(Neither [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/), nor the [venv](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7ded1f0f694f0f99252ea19eca18b74ea5e36cb0#diff-36a32c16a2d1ab045f47d7d4c407cf05R126) or virtualenv sources (or docs) contain any explanation - a [commit message in virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/commit/993ba1316a83b760370f5a3872b3f5ef4dd904c1) refers to "convention")

Comment: I think the commit message is the best you'll get. Everything else will be pure speculation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"I think the commit message is the best you'll get. Everything else will be pure speculation." ([Bryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826134/why-is-the-bin-directory-called-differently-scripts-on-windows#comment74690511_43826134), refering to the [commit message in virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/commit/993ba1316a83b760370f5a3872b3f5ef4dd904c1))

Comment: HAHAHA Wow I did not expect that XD

"Use Scripts/ on Windows, as that seems to be the convention" 


Thanks!

Comment: and It seems that Ian Bicking names it after the directory name in the python installation folder, you have `Scripts` there too!

Answer (score 3):

Most ms-windows programs have a GUI which is started by an icon or menu-entry. So there is no need for a standardized location for binaries (which is then put in the `$PATH`) such as UNIX has. Also, the name `bin` wouldn't *mean* anything like it does to UNIX users.

Additionaly, ms-windows only has a very primitive package management (if you can even call it package management), so applications tend to be installed in their own directory tree where they won't interfere with each other.