# No activate in venv

Tags: python, python-venv

There is no activate script in my virtual environment's bin folder.
Only files are: python, python3, python3.9.

How to fix my environment without deleting it? I'm using venv not virtualenv. I'm using Linux.

My problem is similar to this one -
[There is no activate when I am trying to run my virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687841/there-is-no-activate-when-i-am-trying-to-run-my-virtual-env)

One of answers says I should run.

> python3.7 -m venv venv

But I don't understand this syntax. Should I literally write python3.9 -m venv venv into my terminal? Will it fix my enviroment?

Also I want to say that newly created environments work as expected and all the others too.

Comment: are you using it on window or linux or unix ? Please let me know

Comment: I'm using linux

Comment: "python3.7 -m venv venv"  you had create virtual environment with python3.7 that's issue. Please use "python3.9 -m venv venv" or simply remove extra version of python and keep one.

Comment: I created it with python3.9 - in bin folder there are 3.9 files. This 3.7 line was just an example from this post with problem similar to mine.

Comment: now did you found the venv/bin/activate ?

Comment: It's there. But I want to fix my old environment, not to create new.

Comment: its the version conflicts. Sorry but i have no idea about it.Thanks

Comment: Yes, `python3.7 -m venv venv` should be typed into your terminal. This calls the command `python3.7` (i.e. the Python interpreter version 3.79), and runs module `venv` with argument `venv` (which will be the name of the virtual environment folder).

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with python 3.10, I had to install venv for my version otherwise I was missing the activate script. (I am using the deadsnake ppa on ubuntu) after this the activate script appears when creating new venv.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
```

I documented the full python 3.10 on Ubuntu installation [here](https://blog.cetinich.net/content/2021/2021-python-tips/#install-python-3-10-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score -1):

i think [this is helpfull for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs)

but for basic use it like this:

```
python3.7 -m venv myenvname
source myenvname/bin/activate
```

and if activate isnt there try to find that in sub directories